# Inherited a HTML file with hard links to static files

Tags: html, django

I've inherited a large number of files with direct links to static files like `<img src="images/logo.png" />` when it should be `<img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" />`. Shy of writing my own script, is there a tool I can use to convert from static to dynamic links (are those the correct terms)? I'm using PyCharm too, if that has any tools I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regular expression. Search for this:

```
src="([^'"]+)"
```

Replace with this:

```
src="{% static '\1' %}"
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/yJ7cO1/1

Comment: For IntelliJ, you need to use $ instead of \ to use the result of the previous regex.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421797/regex-backreferences-in-intellij

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problem solved by above solution .... But think.... here if you want to change the some varibale in Pycharm ....
Step...
1.

```
Right click on the variable that you want to change and go for **Refactor**
```

Pycharm

Comment: Renaming of multiple variables is not available in HTML files with PyCharm. Even if it was, I would have to do it with every different instance which is basically what I'm trying not to do.